# Does a map that preserves lengths of rectifiable curves preserve lengths of all curves?

Tags: metric-spaces, riemannian-geometry, isometry, metric-geometry

Let $X,Y$ be length spaces, and let $\, f:X \to Y$ be a map.

Suppose that $f$ preserves the lengths of all rectifiable curves in $X$, i.e for every (continuous) path $\alpha$ such that $L_X(\alpha) < \infty$, $L_Y(f \circ \alpha)=L_X(\alpha)$.

**Question:** Is it true that $f$ preserves lengths of all paths, rectifiable or not?
i.e assume $L_X(\alpha) = \infty$. Is it true that $L_Y(f \circ \alpha)= \infty$?

In other words, does $f$ take non-rectifiable curves to non-rectifiable curves?

Does anything change if we assume $X,Y$ are Riemannian manifolds?

---

A naive approach would be as follows:

If $L_X(\alpha)=\infty$, then perhaps we can break $\alpha$ by restrictions $\alpha_n=\left.\alpha\right|_{I_n}$, such that $n \le L_X(\alpha_n) < \infty$, and so $L_Y(f \circ \alpha) \ge L_Y(f \circ \alpha_n)=L_X(\alpha_n) \ge n$. However, not every non-rectifiable curve can be broken in this way- think of the Koch's snowflake- every non-trivial restriction of it has an infinite length.

Comment: What are length spaces? Are they path-connected subsets of $\mathbb R^n$ or you think of something more general?

Comment: A length space is a metric space with an intrinsic metric. (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intrinsic_metric)

Comment: What does "the length of a nonrectifiable path" mean?

Comment: @JackLee It does not really mean anything important. The definition I am working with is as follows: A curve is non-rectifiable if the supremum of "..." over all partitions is infinite. (In that case one might say its length is infinite). I am merely asking if a map which preserves (finite) lengths of curves, necessarily maps nonrectifiable curves to non-rectifiable curves. (Perhaps my phrasing of the question was not ideal). I might add that I am only interested in paths whose domain is a compact interval, though I am not sure this limitation has any significance.

Answer (score 3):

On $M:=\mathbb{E}^3$, we have a metric
$$ g
=dx^2+dy^2+\omega^2,\ \omega=xdy-dz
$$ 
 Consider a projection $$\pi : (M,g)
 \rightarrow (\mathbb{E}^2,dx^2+dy^2),\ \pi (x,y,z)=(x,y)$$

Note that $$ d\pi \ V =(1,0),\ d\pi\ W=(0,1) $$

where $V=(1,0,0),\ W= (0,1,x)$ Since $V,\ W$ are orthonormal so
$d\pi$ is isometry on $(V,W)$

i) Define a new metric on $M$ : If $c(t)$ is a curve in $M$ from $p$
to $q$ s.t. $g(X,c'(t))=0$, where $\{ V,W,X\}$ is orthonormal frame
for $g$, then
$$d(p,q)={\rm inf}_c\ {\rm length}_g\ c$$

ii) $d(p,q) <\infty$ Here if the distance is obtained by $c$, then
${\rm length}_d\ c= d(p,q)={\rm length}\ \pi\circ c$

iii) $c(t)=(0,0,t)$ Note that $d(
c(t),c(t+\epsilon))=C\sqrt{\epsilon} $ for some $C$
So $c([0,1])$ has infinite length wrt $d$

[**Updated**]----

i) Define a new metric on $M$ :

If $c(t)$ is a piecewise smooth path in
$M$ from $p$ to $q$ s.t. $c'(t)\in (V,W)$ (We call it admissible
path) then
$$d(p,q)={\rm inf}_c\ {\rm length}_g\ c$$
Here $d(\cdot,\cdot)$ is Carnot-Caratheodory distance which gives to
$M$ structure of metric space Here $d$ is finite

ii) Every two pts can be connected by admissible
path (cf Chow-Rashevsky Connectivity Theorem)

iii) $G=\mathbb{E}^3$ acts on $M$ transitively and
isometrically :

$$
a=(x,y,z),\ a\cdot (x_1,y_1,z_1)=(x+x_1,y+y_1,z+z_1+xy_1) $$

Note that orthonormal vector fields $V,\ W$ are invariant under
$G$-action Hence action is isometric

iv) Ball-Box Theorem : $$P_r^c\subset B^d_r((0,0,0))
\subset P_r^C $$

where $B^d_r(p)$ is $r$-ball at $p$ wrt $d$ and $P_r^c$ is $$
[-cr,cr]\times [-cr,cr]\times [-cr^2,cr^2]\subset \mathbb{E}^3$$

By $iii)$ we have $x_k:=  (0,0,\frac{k}{n}),\
d(x_k,x_{k+1})=d(x_{k+1},x_{k+2})$ And Ball-Box theorem implies that
$$ d(x_0,x_1)=\frac{C_1}{\sqrt{n}}$$ for some $C_1$ Hence $$
\infty \leftarrow \sum_{k=1}^n d(x_k,x_{k+1}) < {\rm length}\ c$$
where $c : [0,1]\rightarrow M,\ c(t)=(0,0,t) $

Hence we have $$0={\rm length}\ \pi\circ c\neq {\rm length}\ c
=\infty$$

v) Note that by definition of $d$, smooth admissible path
is minimal geodesic in a small neighborhood By EXE 5.4.7, in fact
any two pt can be connected by smooth minimal geodesic

So since $d\pi$ is isometry $\pi$ preserves length of admissible
path

vi) Assume that $c_n\rightarrow c$ in point wise, ${\rm
length}\ c<\infty$ and $c_n$ is admissible path

Note that $$ {\rm length}\ c=\lim\ {\rm length}\ c_n= \lim\ {\rm
length}\ \pi\circ c_n \geq {\rm length}\ \pi\circ c
$$ since $\pi\circ c_n\rightarrow\pi\circ c$ in point wise

If last inequality is strict assume that
$$c([a,b])\cap c_n([a,b]) =\{ c(a)=c_n(a), c(b)=c_n(b)\}$$
 and $c_n=\alpha_1\cup \alpha_2$ where $\alpha_1|[a,t],\ \alpha_2
|[t,b]$ are smooth admissible Here we change $\alpha_i$ with a
smooth minimal geodesic $\alpha_i'$ s.t. $$ \alpha_1(a)=
\alpha_1'(a),\ \alpha_2(b)=\alpha_2'(b),\
\alpha_1'(t)=\alpha_2'(t)=c(t) $$

From this infinitely many process we obtain equality

**[Riemannian Case]**

(1) If $c: [0,1]\rightarrow M$ is a curve then define a curve $c_n$
to be a broken geodesic joining $\{ c(\frac{k}{n} )\}_{k=0}^n $.
Hence $c$ is a pointwise limit of $c_n$.

(2) That is any curve $c$ is a limit of sequence of curves $c_n$ of
finite lengths. If $f$ is a weak path isometry, then $f$ is short.
Hence $f\circ c$ is a pointwise limit of $f\circ c_n$. Note that
$${\rm length}\ c=\lim\ {\rm length}\ c_n=\lim\ {\rm length}\
 f\circ c_n= {\rm length}\ f\circ c$$

Comment: Thanks. I am trying to understand some details: (1) Do you consider $\pi:(M,d) \to (\mathbb{E}^2,euc)$ to be the map which preserves finite lengths but take a path with infinite length ($c$) to a point? (2) I am not sure why $d(
c(\frac{k}{n}),c(\frac{k+1}{n}))$ is even finite? If I understood correctly you limit the "legal" paths to paths which are always tangent to $\operatorname{span}(V,W)$. I do not see how $(0,0,\frac{k}{n}),(0,0,\frac{k+1}{n})$ can be connected by such a path.

Comment: (1) Yes $c$ has infinite length But $\pi\circ c([0,1])$ is point so
that length is $0$

(2) For $d((0,0,0),(0,0,z))=\pi^{-1}\sqrt{|z|}$, please see second
paragraph from the bottom in 192p, a course in metric geometry -
Burago, Burago, and Ivanov

Comment: $d(c(t),c(t+\epsilon))$ is finite since there is a curve tangent to $(V,W)$  between these two pts This is followed since $\{ V,W,[V,W]\}$ is basis at any pt. For detail see the reference.

Comment: Thanks, I have looked at the book (I am studying it anyway, but I haven't got that far yet...but this stuff looks really cool). By the way, it seems you are also claiming convexity, i.e that the distance between any two points is realized by a minimizing path. Does that also follows from some more general claim?

Comment: Frankly I do not know whether $(M,d)$ is ${\bf geodesic}$ But from vector field $V,\ W$ we have two flows $h_i$ So when we go from $p$ to $q$ we has path which is finite union of segments of $h_i$ Here the limit of length exists so that it is ${\bf intrinsic}$

Comment: First, the fact $d$ is intrinsic is almost by definition,no? (It is defined as infimum of lengths of certain paths w.r.t some length structure, see proposition 2.4.1 in Burago's book). Second, I am not sure what exactly are you claiming in ii). I think you are trying to show $\pi:(M,d) \to (\mathbb{E}^2,euc)$ preserves (finite) lentghs. For that you must take an arbitrary path $c$ in $M$, s.t $L_d(c) < \infty$ and show $L_e(\pi \circ c)=L_d(c)$. If I am not mistaken,...

Comment: this is supposed to follow from the fact that every path $c$ s.t $L_d(c) < \infty$ must be consistent with the relevant distribution, and in that case $L_d(c)=L_g(c)$ (the last equality seems plausible to me, but I am not entirely sure how to justify it). Now you are using the fact $\pi$ is an isometry when restricted to the distribution. Is this the reasoning you were thinking of?

Comment: Hi again:) I wonder: your example is "sub-Riemannian". Do you have an example in a purely Riemannian setting, or do you think that such a thing cannot happen there?

Comment: In Riemannian case it is true. If $c: [0,\infty)\rightarrow M$ is unit speed curve of infinite length, then define $c_n :[n,n+1]\rightarrow M$ Then each $c_n$ is mapped into a curve of length $1$. Then image of $c$ has an infinite length.

Comment: I don't think that every continuous curve can be "partitioned" into sub-curves of finite length, even in a Riemannian manifold (think of a fractal in a plane,no?, every sub-curve with an open domain, will have infinite length). In that case, this argument will fail, isn't it? Perhaps I am missing something.

Comment: You are right. I add an explanation about this.

Comment: Thanks. I understood points (2),(3) of your argument (which answer my question, thanks). I am not sure what you meant to say in point $(1)$? (What is the context there?)

Comment: It is not needed. I fix it.

Answer (score 1):

I am filling some details in HK Lee's great answer.

We want to prove $\pi:(M,d) \to (\mathbb{E}^2,euc)$ preserves (finite) lentghs of paths.

Take an arbitrary path $c$ in $M$, s.t $L_d(c) < \infty$. We claim that $L_e(\pi \circ c)=L_d(c)$. By the isomteric nature of $\pi$ it is enough to show that $c$ is consistent with the distribution $V,W$ (i.e $\dot c(t) \in \operatorname{span}(V(c(t)),W(c(t))  $ ) and that $L_d(c)=L_g(c)$.

**Lemma 1:**

$L_d(c) < \infty \Rightarrow \dot c(t) \in \operatorname{span}(V(c(t)),W(c(t))  $.

Assuming the lemma, we proceed as follows:

$L_g \le L_d$, since both $d,d_g$ are intrinsic and $d_g \le d$ (since in $d$ we allow less paths) so $L_g=L_{d_g} \le L_d$.

The argument in the proof of proposition 2.3.12 in the book a course in metric geometry (Burago,Burago,Ivanov) shows that $L_{d_g} \ge L_d$.

---

**Proof of lemma 1:**

To complete...